# ng-show angular js asp.net

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I receive a json object via an api rest, I want to display the pictogram with ng-show if I have places
json :

```
 {
    date:"2016-06-30T01:01:01"
    id:2
{place: 54, pol: 1, type: "Inside"}
{place: 54, pol: 1, type: "Inside"}
{place: 54, pol: 1, type: "Inside"}
{place: 54, pol: 1, type: "Inside"}
 }
```

Controller:

```
 $scope.LoadAllSpots = function (){
        SpotConfigurationService.GetListSpots(function (datas) {
            $scope.CAMs = datas;
            console.log(datas);
        }, function (datas) {

        });
  }
directive :


template: '<div>' + 
                 '  <div class="titles" ng-class="{true: \'SelectedAccordionStyle\',false:\'\'}[showMe]"><span class="svg_Red_Heading" ng-show ="!CAMs[0].place" > <img class="Svg-PictoRougeHeading" src="/Resources/Common/alerte.svg"/></span> {{title}} <a class="more-less glyphicon glyphicon-plus" ng-class="{true: \'glyphicon glyphicon-minus\', false:\'glyphicon glyphicon-plus\'}[showMe]" data-ng-click="OpenAccordion()"></a><button  ng-show ="showMe"> {{loadedFilter | i18n :\'ConfigurationSpotCAMValid\':\'Validate the entry\'}}</button> </div>' +
                '<div data-ng-show="showMe" data-ng-transclude=""></div>' +
                '</div>',
```

Comment: the tag angular is for angular 2+ projects and yours is 1+, change it to angularjs please

Comment: okey deblaton how are you

Answer (score 0):

You can check for that inside the controller and assign a value to a variable if the condition is met,

```
for (var s in $scope.CAMs {
    if (SoftwareBadges[s]["place"])
        $scope.showme = true;
}
```

Comment: helllo saajjtharan,
$scope.ShowConfiguration = function(){

     for (var s in $scope.CAMs) {
         if (SoftwareBadges[s]["place"])
             $scope.showme = true;
     }
  }
how i can do in template please

Comment: i do that bu software badge its waht please :<span class="svg_Red_Heading" ng-show="showMe " > <img class="Svg-PictoRougeHeading" src="/Resources/Common/alerte.svg"/></span>

Comment: but i want display picto when i have the places not free in my json